# xcode compilation errors after xcode 6 update

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Since I upgraded to xcode 6 my project do not compile anymore, I cleaned several time, restarted, deleted the derived data but it didn't help

So I went back to xcode 5 and I also have errors now on xcode 5
My project is a working project from the repository and it's working on my colleague's mac...

I didn't change anything so I don't understand and will aprreciate any help

the errors

error: unable to open executable '/Users/mobiledev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bqkgvjwrncaywqgcyydyxfwxsvio/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp'

ld: framework not found AVKit for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same trouble, I've just set the target membership in File Inspector of my framework. 
Find AVKit framework in your project and try my method, may be it will help.

Comment: But I don't have and never had AVKit in my project, and I don't find it if I want to add it